# Neat/Approximate formula for maximum number of "almost orthogonal" vectors in a complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-product

In a $d$ dimensional vector space defined over $\mathbb{C}$, how do I calculate the largest number $N(\epsilon, d)$ of vectors $\{V_i\}$ which satisfies the following properties. Here $\epsilon$ is smaller but finite compared to 1.

$$\langle V_i, V_i\rangle = 1$$

$$|\langle V_i, V_j\rangle| \leq \epsilon, i \neq j$$

Some examples are as follows.

1. $N(0, d)$ = d
2. $N\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2\right)$ = 3
3. $N\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 2\right) = 6$

How do I obtain any general formula for $N(\epsilon, d)$. Even an approximate form for $N(\epsilon, d)$ in the large $d$ and small $\epsilon$ ($\epsilon \ll 1$) limit works fine for me.

Comment: crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296448/maximum-number-of-almost-orthogonal-vectors-in-a-complex-vector-space --- please don't do that, in order to avoid duplication of efforts.

Comment: this is the content of the [Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson–Lindenstrauss_lemma) : $N\simeq e^{d\epsilon^2/8}$

Comment: Hi @CarloBeenakker, I crossposted this to increase the audience, and to avoid duplication of efforts I would edit the question on other platform if I find my answer somewhere. Regarding your comment, is there a version of JL lemma for high dimensional vector spaces defined over ℂ ? This is very close to the formula I was looking for, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Related question and answers. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24864/almost-orthogonal-vectors/184677#184677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma that you can use is derived by L. Welch in [Lower bounds on the maximum cross correlation of signals](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055219)  (1974). This paper is behind a paywall, I quote the result from [arXiv:0909.0206](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0206)

Consider $N=d^{k}$ unit vectors $V_i$ in $\mathbb{C}^d$ with $N>d$. Then the maximal inner product $\epsilon=\max_{i\neq j}|\langle V_i|V_j\rangle|$ satisfies the inequality
$$\epsilon^{2k}\geq \frac{1}{N-1}\left(\frac{N}{{{d+k-1}\choose{k}}}-1\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look.

Comment: see also the answer given at https://www.physicsoverflow.org/42367