# Distance of low-rank matrices to the identity for the $\infty$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, lower-bounds

I am trying to get a lower bound (or even the exact value) of

$$
\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} \|X - I_n\|_{\infty} \enspace \text{s.t.} \enspace \mbox{Rank}(X) = m
$$

where $m \leq n$, and the infinity norm is

$$ \| X \|_{\infty} := \max_{ij}|X_{ij}| $$

I have a very simple lower bound, obtained with norm equivalence:

$$\|X - I_n\|_{\infty} \geq \frac{1}{n} \|X - I_n\|_F\geq \frac{\sqrt{n - m}}{n}$$

but this is obviously not tight, and experiments suggest that the scaling is wrong.

Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Is the infinity norm the induced infinity norm? Or the Schatten infinity norm (i.e., operator/spectral norm)? For the induced norm, I'm pretty sure the minimum equals $1$ for all $m < n$. For the Schatten norm, I think the norm equivalence factor should be $1/\sqrt{n}$, not $1/n$.

Comment: What is the regime you are interested in: $m$ close to $n$, or $m$ small? Do you need a lower or an upper bound for the smallest possible norm? And, seconding the previous comment, what do you mean by the infinity norm?

Comment: The inifinity norm above is the induced norm: $\|X\|_{\infty} = \max_{ij}|X_{ij}|$. I have edited the original post. Do you have an explanation about why this should be one?  I think you can easily get 1/2 by using rank one matrices.

Comment: I am interested in any regime, but the most interesting would be n, m $\rightarrow + \infty$ with n / m a constant.

Comment: @PAb - You're right -- ignore my comment about the minimum equaling $1$.

Comment: You should get precise asymptotics from the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24864/almost-orthogonal-vectors

Comment: Relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07474

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem 1.1 from Alon's paper ["Perturbed identity matrices have high rank: proof and applications"](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/identity1.pdf) says that if $\|X-I_n\|_\infty<c$ with $1/(2\sqrt n)<c<1/4$, then $m\gg \log n/(c^2\log(1/c))$ with an absolute implicit constant. This is exactly what you need: if $X$ is close to the identity matrix in the infinity norm, then the rank of $X$ is large. Incidentally, ALon's bound is sharp up to a logarithmic factor; therefore, you cannot expect to get much better estimates.

Comment: Nice. The argument in my answer is precisely the justification of your last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Your simple lower bound is not so bad, in particular when $m$ is of order $cn$ for $0<c<1$.

Indeed, it follows from the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24864/almost-orthogonal-vectors) that there are unit vectors $u_1,...,u_n$ in $\mathbf{R}^m$ such that $|\langle u_i,u_j\rangle| \leq C \sqrt{\frac{\log n}{m}}$ for every $i \neq j$. Taking $X = (\langle u_i,u_j\rangle)_{i,j}$ yields that the minimum is at most $C \sqrt{\frac{\log n}{m}}$.